# High traffic(30Mpps, 150Gbps) process, Is there a way to clear/flash **from cache** address range/mbuf?

Tags: linux, caching, hpc, dpdk, prefetch

- To process 20Mpps I actively prefetch( and I need to grow to 30Mpps).
- Frames are handled one by one(multi-threads).
- After returning the Mbuf to the dpdk-mempool, there is no reason to hold the old Mbut in the cache.
- **The are a lot of other arrays and memory used to process the frames and like to avoid it flush to memory because the cache is full**. Let's call it non-frames data.

So my question:
**Is there a way to clear **from cache** address range/rte_mbuf?**

Comment: from your explanation it is not fully clear what is `intention on the question`. Hence I will have to assume your question as `in your application using DPDK packet is held in rte_mbuf which you are actively prefetched. You feel or found the struct mbuf or payload content which is prefetched is still in L1 or L2 cache. hence limiting your performance. hence you need to know a way to clear cache content`. If this is right understanding, please update your question with CPU details, and prefetch instruction used. Please note HW cache manager does a real good job in evicting L1 and L2.

Comment: You assume correct, thanks, updated.
About the CPU details, it's Xeon(R) Gold 5220R, why is relevant?

Comment: `why is relevant?` depending upon platform (arm, powerpc, x86, risc) and SKU, the cache level hierarchy, stream prefetch, and eviction, all vary. Even there are HW cache prefetch ISA hints which allow to evict or longer keep the entries quickly. `Please update the code for calculating the buffer in cache holdup for 20Mpps and Instruction for prefetch too`. FYI, smaller L1 and l2 evicts faster, especially with DPDK since you have to process rte_mbuf and payload, you will end up prefetching minimum of 2 cache lines into L1 and L2, assuming your packet processing is done within 64B.

Comment: Instruction like CLFUSH and WRITEFLUSH are available which flushes the caches. In X86 (newer models skylake onwards) there are CLDEMONTE which allows to quickly evict the cache lines. But as mentioned personally HW cache eviction logic really does a good job in evicting unused cache, forcing the cache eviction or range of cachelines adversely effects the performance of the code. Especially with Hyper threading enabled and both sibling threads are sharing same code and same cache space. So please include your methodology for measuring cache effects?

Comment: can you please update 1) the code for calculating the buffer in cache holdup for 20Mpps and 2) Instruction used for prefetch